# Virtual function behavior in derived classes

Tags: c++

Can I have a `virtual` function in the base class and some of my derived classes do have that function and some don't have.

```
class A{
   virtual void  Dosomething();
};

class B : public A{
   void  Dosomething();
};

class C : public A{
  //Does not have Dosomething() function.
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one of my c++ textbook:

> Once a function is declared virtual, it remains virtual all the way down the inheritance, even if the function is not explicitly declared virtual when the derived class overrides it.
>   When the derived class chooses not to override it, it simply inherits its base class's virtual function.

Therefore to your question the answer is No. Class c will use Class A's virtual function.

Comment: If you do not want the derived class to contain a base class function you can `= delete` it in the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

Derived classes do not have to implement all the virtual functions, unless it is a pure virtual function. Even in this case, it will cause an error only when you try to instantiate the derived class( without implementing the pure virtual function ).

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
    public :
   virtual void  foo() = 0; 
};

class B: public A{
    public :
   void  foo(){ std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;}
};

class C: public A{
    void bar();
};

int main() {
    //C temp; The compiler will complain only if this is initialized without
    // implementing foo in the derived class C
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you might get, is to change the access modifier in the derived class, as depicted below.

But, I would consider it bad practice, as it violates Liskov's substitution principle.

If you have a situation like this, you might need to reconsider your class design.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    virtual void doSomething() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void doSomething() override { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; };
};

class C : public A {
private:
    void doSomething() override { std::cout << "C" << std::endl; };
};

int main(int argc, char **args) {
    A a;
    a.doSomething();
    B b;
    b.doSomething();
    C c;
    //c.doSomething(); // Not part of the public interface. Violates Liskov's substitution principle.
    A* c2 = &c;
    c2->doSomething(); // Still possible, even though it is private! But, C::doSomething() is called!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `A& ac = c; ac.doSomething();` is [perfectly valid](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e699f00856ac4d5).

Comment: `class D : public A {
    void doSomething() = delete; };`